# Retrieving properties from the Classpath rather than from resources/config.properties

Tags: java, classpath

I currently have the following method which allows me to pick properties that have been defined in my resources/config.properties file

```
private final Properties properties = new Properties();
{
    final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    try(InputStream config = loader.getResourceAsStream("Resources/config.properties")){
        properties.load(config);
    } catch(IOException e){
        throw new IOError(e);
    }
}
```

But I now want to pick my properties from the classpath so I have moved my config.properties from resources and placed it directly under src. But I'm struggling to know what changes I now need to make to my method to enable me to read from classpath.

Comment: loader.getResourceAsStream("classpath:config.properties");

Comment: @faizakram Thanks for replying. This didn't seem to work I'm afraid.

Comment: ok let me check on my side

Answer (score 1):

```
Check example here

    import java.io.IOError;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

    public class ReaderProp {
        public final Properties properties = new Properties();
        public ReaderProp()
        {
            final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            try(InputStream config = loader.getResourceAsStream("error.properties")){
                properties.load(config);
            } catch(IOException e){
                throw new IOError(e);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ReaderProp  readerProp = new ReaderProp();
            System.out.println(readerProp.properties.get("E1000_SE_ERROR-CODE"));// output E1000
        }
    }

Check error.properties
======================
E1000_SE_ERROR-CODE = E1000
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit new to this but isn't the above reading properties from resources rather than from the classpath?

Comment: where is your resources directory?

Comment: Resources is under \src\Test\Resources. But my .properties file is under src/environment.properties. This is the one I want to be picked up.

Comment: Hope you will find the solution now

Answer (score 0):

//Find another answer

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;   
public class ReaderProp {

        private final Properties configProp = new Properties();

        /**
         * read property file
         * 
         * @param propertyName
         * @param path
         * 
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public ReaderProp(String propertyName, String path) {
            try {
                InputStream in;
                File file;

                if (path.equals("")) {
                    in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyName);
                }
                else {
                    file = new File(path + propertyName);
                    in = new FileInputStream(file);
                }
                configProp.load(in);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ReaderProp  readerProp = new ReaderProp("error.properties",new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"\\src\\");
            System.out.println(readerProp.configProp.get("E1000_SE_ERROR-CODE"));// output E1000
        } 
    }
```

[image]